# Jagged Arrays in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, jagged-arrays

So I want to create an array of arrays and from what I gather, a jagged array is what I need.

I have an array x(i,j) which defines a square nxn matrix of integers. For every iteration of k, two integer values inside this array are swapped to try and better the matrix x(i,j). I need to create an array which stores this matrix x(i,j) after every iteration of k.

To clarify, say if I have

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

And I perform an iteration swapping two elements inside the array:

```
7  2  3
4  5  6
1  8  9
```

I want to be able to store these arrays inside an array to be recalled any time. I've attempted a solution here:

```
Dim y() As Variant 'Declare as a variant to contain arrays
ReDim y(1 To IterationLimit) 'This will be the jagged array

For k = 1 To IterationLimit
'Some code goes here for the swap
    y(k) = x(i,j)
next k
```

Now say I want the 85th iteration. I want to be able to type y(85) [or similar] to pull up the matrix x(i,j) for that particular time.

Hopefully i've explained this well enough. Any help is appreciated, i'm really stuck on this.

edit: deleted code

Comment: when you say you have array `x(i,j)` do `i` and `j` represent the bounds of this array?  Or is `x` an array of arrays, one of whose child arrays is identified by the index `(i,j)`?

Comment: i and j do represent the bounds yes. So for the above example I think would be x(1 to 3, 1 to 3)

Comment: To give you a bit more info, If i was to reference x(2,2) from the matrix above, this would take the value in the second row and the second column, i.e  5. Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: OK, so what is happening when you're doing `y(k) = x(i,j)` is that you're **ONLY** storing `y(k)` as a single value (the itme represented by i/j coordinates in the `x` array).

Comment: If you want to be able to pull up the **entire** array by `y(k)` then you just do `y(k) = x` during your iteration.

Comment: Yes, I have a piece of code in my macro now that is outputting the matrix [Cells(20 + i, 20 + j).Value = y(20)] and the value is the same throughout. But I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: I've given that a try, so i have y(k) = x. Then outside of my loop, i have Cells(20 + i, 20 + j).Value = y(20) (where y(20) is the 20th iteration). But this still displays the same value in all the of array...

Comment: Oh and by the way, i and j are the bounds of the matrix still.

Comment: If you look at the Locals window in the VBE< what does `y(20)` look like?  Also, it is always helpful to post your entire code, rather than just part of your code. As is, the problem could be somewhere else in your code that I cannot see.  I will put an example together showing what I mean...

Comment: Hm ok, i can do that now if you would like? However it's quite lengthy. Shall i just edit my first post?

Comment: Ok, i've posted the sub in my first post now. If you need any explanation of anything i'll be happy to help! Edit: By the way don't pay too much attention to the annotations as i'm using them to help me more than explain right now

Comment: OK yeah that is quite lengthy and I don't have the file/user form, etc. I will post a suggested answer with the VBE showing you how to *view* your array variables, since it seems like you are not doing something correctly to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK. I think you may simply not be assigning the arrays to `y` correctly. As I mentioned in the comments:

`y(k) = x(i,j)` is **ONLY** storing the value represented by i/j coordinates in the `x` array.

In order for `y(k)` to refer to the entire array `x` at that time, you would do:

`y(k) = x`

If that is still not functioning, then perhaps something else is incorrect.  Here is an example where I have a 2x2 (base 0) array called `baseArray`, which I explicitly fill with some values.  I iterate from `i = 0 to itLimit`, and within each iteration, I iterate over the items in the array, multiplying the values by 2, and storing in an array variable `tmpArray`.  After the values have been transformed, I store them in `arrContainer`, and proceed to the next `For i = 0 to itLimit` iteration.

```
Sub FunWithArrays()
Dim itLimit As Integer  '## Iteration limit.'
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim baseArray(2, 2) As Variant '## an example array.'

    '## Put some dummy data in this array.'
    baseArray(0, 0) = 1
    baseArray(0, 1) = 65
    baseArray(0, 2) = 13
    baseArray(1, 0) = 14
    baseArray(1, 1) = 29
    baseArray(1, 2) = 44
    baseArray(2, 0) = 9
    baseArray(2, 1) = 16
    baseArray(2, 2) = 33

Dim tmpArray(2, 2) As Variant '## This will temporarily hold values as we transform them.'
Dim arrContainer() As Variant '## an array of arrays, to store the iteration arrays.'

    itLimit = 2  '## set a max iteration.'

    For i = 0 To itLimit
        '## Transform the base array somehow'
        For j = LBound(baseArray, 1) To UBound(baseArray, 1)
            For k = LBound(baseArray, 2) To UBound(baseArray, 2)
                tmpArray(j, k) = baseArray(j, k) * 2
            Next
        Next
        ReDim Preserve arrContainer(i)
        arrContainer(i) = tmpArray
    Next

    Dim y As Variant
    '## Now, refer to a single iteration stored in the arrContainer variable:

    y = arrContainer(2)

End Sub
```

In this first screenshot, I use the `Locals` window to review the variables and what they contain.  After the first iteration, you can see that `tmpArray` has been populated, and is the same dimensions as `baseArray`, but the values therein have been multiplied by 2.

[image: Screenshot after the first iteration]

Examining the `arrContainer` variable, we see that it has only 1 item, and that item is an array equal to the `tmpArray` that we created in the iteration, above.

[image: Screenshot of arrContainer after the first iteration]

After the last iteration, we can review `arrContainer` and see that it contains 3 items (0 to 2, per our `For i to itLimit` loop).  Each array inside `arrContainer` is equal to one of the arrays created in the iteration above.

[image: Screenshot of arrContainer array of arrays after all iterations]

We can now refer to these items, like:

`Dim y as Variant`
`y = arrContainer(2) '# or any in bounds index could be used instead of "2"'`

And finally using the VBE Locals window to review `y`:

[image: Final screenshot referring to a single array item within arrContainer]

Comment: @David Zemens Oh this is excellent, it's working! The locals window is something that i'd never thought of using before but it proved really useful! And to output to cells i used Cells(20 + i, 20 + j).Value = ArrContainer(80)(i, j) [inside an i and j For loop]. Just one question! What is the purpose of the ReDim Preserve? What does the Preserve do?

Comment: @Matt `ReDim` allows you to re-declare and/or resize an Array. `Preserve` preserve existing values.  The difference between `ReDim arrContainer(3)` and `ReDim Preserve arrContainer(3)` is that the first statement sizes the array with upper bound = 3, but erases its contents, whereas the latter sizes the array with upper bound = 3 while preserving its contents.

Comment: @Matt Further: We have initially dimensioned `arrContainer as Variant` with no bounds, so a statement like `arrContainer(0) = "blah"` will  error.  Each iteration, `ReDim Preserve` makes the array bigger (to accommodate a new value), & preserves existing contents.  You could  `ReDim arrContainer(itLimit-1)` after setting `itLimit`, which would create an array of the correct size.  But when working with loops, often the size is not known in advance so I prefer to `ReDim Preserve` within the loop.